# Countdown to date in windows phone app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, countdown

I'm creating a countdown to a specific date. Days left, Hours left and minutes left have to be shown in a textblock.

Made a flat design in XAML, know how to calculate the timespan. Now I'm in need of a live updater while the app is running.

My Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="myLayoutGrid"
      Background="CadetBlue" Margin="0,-26.667,0,-0.333"
      >

    <TextBlock x:Name="countDays" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="45,150,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Dagen" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="34" Loaded="countDays_Loaded"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="countHours" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="45,200,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Uur" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="30" Loaded="countHours_Loaded"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="countMinutes" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="45,250,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Minuten" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="26" Loaded="countMinutes_Loaded"/>
```

My code;

```
private void countDays_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016 15:00");
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan ts = end - start;

        countDays.Text = string.Format("{0} Dagen", ts.Days);



    }

    private void countHours_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016 15:00");
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan ts = end - start;

        countHours.Text = string.Format("{0} Uur", ts.Hours);

    }

    private void countMinutes_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016 15:00");
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan ts = end - start;

        countMinutes.Text = string.Format("{0} Minuten", ts.Minutes);
    }
```

After i understand the code and why i should use that code, i'd like to clean up my code (put the timer in a class). After that and i studied the HUB app, i will use it in binding element.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should not edit the initial question heavily since it puts answers out of context and then it's no good for anyone else. Opening a new question is totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some sort of timer to periodically refresh the remaining time. Try the follwoing approach:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly DateTime _endDate;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _endDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0);
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += CountDown;
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void CountDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var remainingTime = _endDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

        countDays.Text = string.Format("{0} Dagen", remainingTime.Days);
        countHours.Text = string.Format("{0} Uur", remainingTime.Hours);
        countMinutes.Text = string.Format("{0} Minuten", remainingTime.Minutes);
    }
}
```

To make the code compile remove the `Loaded="countX_Loaded"` eventhandlers from your textblocks in your XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow28009341.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="myLayoutGrid" Background="CadetBlue" Margin="0,-26.667,0,-0.333">
        <TextBlock x:Name="countDays" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="45,150,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Dagen" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="34"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="countHours" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="45,200,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Uur" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="30"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="countMinutes" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="45,250,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Minuten" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Tahoma"
               FontSize="26"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Timer in codebehind could be easiest, fastest and simplest implementation if you are new to WP development, separation of concern and design patterns. Still one shoudl strive away from codebehind development.

Comment: @Mikko that's true. Your approach is definitifly the more prospective one in that regard.

Comment: @khlr. Hmm tried to do this but can't get it to work. I prefer for now this easy option. Because i'am starting with coding. This code also i can read. Maybe i should make public strings so i can bind it to the textblock. (I accept that Mikko's solution is stronger, but my knowledge is not that good (yet).

Comment: @Tezzo what's not working yet? You won't need any public members so far. Yep, Mikko's approach is the more advanced one, you could try to "uprade" to at a later point.

Comment: @khlr It doesn't show up in my app. I understand the logic you used. I removed the on_Loaded events. better I'd  build a new XAMl with only Textblocks. somehow it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Tezzo I've added the XAML. If you create a new test solution and paste these two listings, you should make it work.

Comment: @khlr allright it worked anyway. but it's strating after one minute, so maybe I should set some faster timer.Interval (seconds? maybe, but i don't want the processor be used every second.) But then i get a very strange number in my outcome in my emulator. it gives -735615 Days.

Comment: For one initial countdown you could invoke the method one time in the constructor, right after `_timer.Start();`, do `CountDown(null, null);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69065/discussion-between-khlr-and-tezzo).

Comment: Thnx for helping. I did parse a string to get it right. maybe my failure to understand how to implement overload methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using MVVM pattern when ever you develop applications for WP8 using C#/XAML.

This means you create a `View` (e.g. XAML Window) and then a separated context for it's data, named `ViewModel`. When ever data is changed you need to notify the view of changes by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

To make periodic changes you should use Task-based Asynchronous Pattern. This way your UI thread is not blocked. This would be easiest by using a `Task`.

Of course there's several other ways to do this but this is what I'd recommend.

Then your application could look something like the following.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<!-- This would be <phone:PhoneApplicationPage in WP8 app -->
<!-- e.g. phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"-->
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="116"
        Width="250">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApplication1:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <!-- Bind displayed text to MainViewModel's CountDown property -->
        <!-- This way it automically updates the TextBlock whenever value is changed -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountDown}" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>        
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
// No code added here, this is the initial class structure.
// This needs to be in same namespace as MainWindow/Page XAML (partial)
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
// This would be plain C# class in WP8, too
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // This event takes care of notifying the page so it updates
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _countDown;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // Day to countdown to
            DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5d);

            // Start new thread
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Loop until target date and update value every second
                    while (DateTime.Now <= targetDate)
                    {
                        // Format and set new value
                        CountDown = (targetDate - DateTime.Now).ToString("d'd 'h'h 'm'm 's's'");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    // Final value
                    CountDown = "It's tiem!";
                });
        }

        // Value displayed in Page's TextBlock
        public string CountDown
        {
            get { return _countDown; }
            set { _countDown = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }

        // This is INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you counter looking like below, which updates once per second and does not freeze UI.

[image]
(Example is for .NET 4.5 WPF application but it should be 99%...100% same for Windows Phone apps).

Instead of simple `while` loop you could take the longer road and replace it with a timer, if you wish, by replacing the `Task.Factory.StartNew` block with

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        int difference = (int) (targetDate - now).TotalSeconds;
        CountDown = difference >= 0 ? 
                    (targetDate - now).ToString("d'd 'h'h 'm'm 's's'") : 
                    "It's tiem!";
        if (difference < 0)
            timer.Stop();
    };
timer.Start();
```

Comment: maybe this is the best implementation, but my knowledge is not great enough to fix this. I'am building from the "Blank App" in visual studio.

Comment: Example is complete, you could modify it to your needs.

Comment: Iám thankfull. but i don't know how to implement cause i'm learning. T bad This not make sense know. I just started with a blank App, a textblock.

Comment: Complete code is there. I can add comments to it but other that... you have to manage or get new answers.

Comment: I agree to that. I sure will getting back with your solution when I'am further with mastering winphone 8 XAML and C#. Thanks in advance. and i agree That is better to do the rocketscience elsewhere and use Xaml only to present data.

Comment: Also thnx, now for sure your solution is more advanced. but i'm learning and this is way to far for now.